# Can I solve this using oracle db listener?

Tags: oracle11g

Try to be more clear, I'm in lack of ideas in this problem, even it sounds like a classic.

My application is running on weblogic 10.3.3 application server, and for database I am using Oracle database 11g. My problem is that there is table in db, let's say "user.", there is column, let's say "columnA", in this table. This table is updating by some module of application.

What I want if when value of column is "abc.", then I have to show alert to console(IP). {IP can be retrieved from DB as it is configured in DB. this ip will be other linux system other than linux machine where oracle database is installed.} Updating is continuously done on my table from module of application. Please tell me from where should I start?, what should I read. I am not able to understand what should be approach. Any help is much appreciated.

Can u provide me any begginner.s link of oracle db listener?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to look at setting up a Trigger in the database

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/triggers.htm

Comment: I read oracle trigger but after that how will i generate trigger to other machine

Comment: I've never used triggers myself, so I'm not sure of the mechanics, but my guess would be that there would be a way for a trigger to launch a command-line app of some kind that could then alert the other machine.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to a trigger would be to log update queries against the table (to a log file) and have a process monitor the log, sending out alerts when something happens.